# Output analog and hdmi sound over ALSA on RPi3

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa, kodi

I'm trying to setup my Raspberry Pi 3 in such a way that both analog and hdmi audio are working in Kodi simultaneously with ALSA. So the driver should be ALSA (in that way I should be able to use the LADSPA plugins to delay the analog stream (next step) :-)).

I've been crawling Google for quite some hours now and I don't understand how to setup ALSA correctly.

The only way I'm getting both analog and HDMI audio is by selecting that option in Kodi but the stream must go through ALSA (which it does not in that case). Does anyone have a clue how to set this up?

The hardware in the Pi seems be setup as follows:

- Analog sound: Card 0 Device 0
- HDMI Sound: Card 0 Device 1

For now I'm only able to switch the output between analog and HDMI with this command:

- `amixer cset numid=3 1` > analog audio
- `amixer cset numid=3 2` > HDMI audio